# adb: event when Android phone connects to Windows

Tags: android, winapi, event-handling, usb, adb

Is there a simple way to get an event on Windows when an android phone connects **via adb**?

It should work in plain-C with Windows API (i.e., no Java!) and should not rely on polling. I.e., I don't want to call `adb list` in a loop. I'd rather have a small few kB footprint exe running in background that gets notified via an event or a window message when a device connects.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such event in the [ADB protocol](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/protocol.txt) (also see [this](http://blogs.kgsoft.co.uk/2013_03_15_prg.htm)). You would have to poll the active list regularly.

Comment: connect to `adb server`, issue `host:track-devices` command and wait - no need to poll

Comment: Thanks guys. I found another promising solution: I use `RegisterDeviceNotification` and wait for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. However, this only notifies me about a device "SAMSUNG Mobile USB Composite Device". This in turn has the children "SAMSUNG-SGH-747" (file access), "SAMSUNG Mobile USB Modem" and "SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface". I want to issue an action is the last device exists on the system. Now I could just check inside `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. Is there any simple way to do this, possibly without the bulky adb.exe? Maybe with AdbWinApi.dll? Is there docu on it? (I found none!)